# inputAccessoryView on UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, inputaccessoryview

It's easy as pie to add an `inputAccessoryView` on a `UITextField`, `UITextView`, or `UISearchBar`. However, there's no obvious and easy way to add one for your basic `UIView` as far as I can tell!

I have a `UIView` subclass that follows the `UIKeyInput` protocol. It receives keyboard input to do stuff that isn't related to entering text, so I'd rather not force it to subclass the former specified views because it adds bloat and would expose a bunch of properties that don't do anything, plus I'd need to work around the text entry that occurs natively to those classes (more bloat).

However, my `UIView` does need an input accessory view on its presented keyboard to function correctly.

Are there any simple ways to go about this? Do I have to register as an observer to the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` in my `UIView` subclass and add a subview, as an accessory view, to it manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try simply adding the inputAccessoryView method to your viewController?
I believe it gets called when the keyboard is shown, so you don't actually have to assign one to each textField or view.

```
- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView
{
    if (!inputAccessoryView)
    {
        CGRect accessFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 77.0);
        inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:accessFrame];
        inputAccessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        UIButton *compButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        compButton.frame = CGRectMake(313.0, 20.0, 158.0, 37.0);
        [compButton setTitle: @"Word Completions" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [compButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [compButton addTarget:self action:@selector(completeCurrentWord:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [inputAccessoryView addSubview:compButton];
    }
    return inputAccessoryView;
}
```

Comment: Definitely set me on the correct path. I didn't realize `inputAccessoryView` was a method of UIResponder! So any view or view controller can use it if overwritten :)